# The words average from a File

Tags: python-2.7, file

I have this questions: Write a program that will calculate the average word length of a text  stored in a file (i.e the sum of all the lengths of the word tokens in the text, divided by the number of word tokens).

my code:

```
allword = 0
words = 0
average = 0
with open('/home/......', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
       me =  i.split()
       allword += len(me)
       words += len(i)
       average += allword / float(words) 

     print average
```

so , i have 4 line and 55 characters without computer blank space, i come from average:  27.54 .... and i think that the result not gut is...
Can anybody with simple words tell me,  where are that problem....
Very Thanks!

Comment: Why 27.54 is not gut? What you expect the value to be, and why?

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! , i think that it are not gut  because i have several answer from this question to see , a example https://github.com/R4meau/46-simple-python-exercises/blob/master/exercises/ex38.py   and are"little" different as mine.....

Comment: Sprechen Sie Deutsch?

Comment: Ein Bissen , aber ich komme nicht aus deutschland....

Comment: @mustaccio can you please tell me you opinion about my code?

Answer (score 0):

@mustaccio

Maybe 27.54 to high...now the code with a little change.....

```
allword = 0
words = 0
average = 0
with open('/home/....', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
       me = "".join(i.split(" "))
       allword += len(me)
       words += len(i)
       average +=  allword / float(words)
    print average
```

Now i come 4.32....